# C++ read from file

Tags: c++, file-io

How should I read this file if I know how many int values are after the first value but I don't know how many values are after them. My problem is when I have to read the lines that contains 2 values.

**Edit: This is my file**

```
5
27
15
42
17
35
20 1
28 2
43 3
```

Here is what I tried:

```
fin >> n;
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    fin >> part[i];

while(!fin.eof())
{
    nrT++;
    fin >> tric[nrT][0];
    fin >> tric[nrT][1];
}
```

Comment: Since all you know is how many lines there are, read each line into a string and then parse it apart if it might contain two numbers

Comment: What is going on? I saw like 20 questions about reading from file using C++... in the last 10 days!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int a,b; fin >> a >> b; nrT++)
{
    tric[nrT][0] = a;
    tric[nrT][1] = b;
}
```

Comment: why do you need a and b? Can't you use tric[nrT][0] and tric[nrT][1] directly?

Comment: @istrandjev: It's reading until failure.  If this was a vector, instead of an array, we would be using push_back.  We wouldn't want to extend the vector, and then read into it, because the last values would be invalid.  Even though this appears to be an array, and not a vector, I prefer to keep my style consistent.  Actually, as far as we know, tric could be a map or an array of maps, and in that case, we would be inserting in-valid values into the map.

Answer (score 0):

Treat an end of line character the same as you would a space character, and try to parse everything that's not either of those. If you use [Unicode aware regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) there's already a group which does this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into string streams. (I don't know the code off the top of my head). They are like cin, but you can initialize them with data from a file. Then you can use the >> operator to extract data from it and it knows how to pull out the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `fin.eof()`.  That function is only useful after a read
has failed.  Something like the following should work, however:

```
fin >> n;
if ( !fin || n > size( part ) ) {
    //  Error...
}
for ( i = 0; i != n; ++ i ) {
    fin >> part[i];
    if ( !fin ) {
        //  Error...
    }
}
while ( nrT < size( tric ) && fin >> tric[nrT][0] >> tric[nrT][1] ) {
    ++ nrT;
}
```

For better validation, you might want to read the file line by line, and
extract one or two elements from the line, depending on where you are in
the file.  Another improvement would be to use `std::vector` for the
containers, and `push-back`—that way, you don't need any bounds
checking.

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line, the look for spaces in the line. If there are, use the method substring. Finally, convert the substrings obtained to integers. There are tons of examples on the internet:

[substring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

[String to integer conversion](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/312790-converting-c-string-to-int/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry but no, I think the time I´d spend writing it down is the same you´ll spend reading how find() and substring() work, plus the time to copy and paste code from my second link :-D