# Reading 2D data from tab delimited file and store in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, text-files, fstream

I am trying to read a text file of the format:

```
5
1.00   0.00
0.75   0.25
0.50   0.50
0.25   0.75
0.00   1.00
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int totalDataPoints; // this should be the first line of textfile i.e. 5
std::vector<double> xCoord(0); //starts from 2nd line, first col
std::vector<double> yCoord(0); //starts from 2nd line, second col
double tmp1, tmp2;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::fstream inFile;

    inFile.open("file.txt", std::ios::in);

    if (inFile.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Could not open file" << std::endl;
        return(0);
    } 

    int count = 0;

     while (!inFile.eof()) { 
         inFile >> tmp1;
         xCoord.push_back(tmp1);
         inFile >> tmp2;
         yCoord.push_back(tmp2);
         count++;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < totalDataPoints; ++i) {
         std::cout << xCoord[i] << "    " << yCoord[i] << std::endl;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting results. My final aim is to put this as function and call the x, y values as an object of a class.

Comment: You never set `totalDataPoints` to anything. Similar: [C++ read from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943949/c-read-from-file)

Comment: Please do not test `if(stream.fail())` or `if(stream.eof())`, unless you know what are you doing. Just test `if(stream)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Numeric Data from a Text File in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: What happened when you stepped through this code in a debugger? Was it what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int totalDataPoints;` is a global variable and since you are not initializing it with a value it is going to be 0 initialized.  Then in your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalDataPoints; ++i) {
     std::cout << xCoord[i] << "    " << yCoord[i] << std::endl;
}
```

You are going to do anything since `i < totalDataPoints`(`0 < 0`) is `false`.  I suspect you meant to use

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
     std::cout << xCoord[i] << "    " << yCoord[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Or have

```
totalDataPoints = count;
```

Before the for loop.

I would also suggest you do not use `while (!inFile.eof())` to control the reading of the file.  To fix it You can use

```
 while (inFile >> tmp1 && inFile >> tmp2) { 
     xCoord.push_back(tmp1);
     yCoord.push_back(tmp2);
     count++;
 }
```

This will ensure the loop will only run while there is data to read.  For more information see: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: yes, it works. for totalDataPoints = xCoord.size(); I removed total points from text file i.e. 5. now I can see the results. How can I make a Class file for this?

Comment: @TheCoder *Class file*?  What is that?

Comment: @TheCoder: It's not maintained according your input which take file.txt cz first line in file.txt is   totalDataPoints 5. According this code, you can not take this

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple change needed in your code. You can not take `totalDataPoints` which is provide from `file.txt` in first line. Then you take every line until reach last.

```
int count = 0;

    inFile>>totalDataPoints;

     while (!inFile.eof()) {
         inFile >> tmp1;
         xCoord.push_back(tmp1);
         inFile >> tmp2;
         yCoord.push_back(tmp2);
         count++;
     }
```

By **for loop** you can do this like, Here `int count = 0` is unnecessary:

```
inFile>>totalDataPoints;

    for (int i=0; i<totalDataPoints; i++)
    {
        inFile >> tmp1;
         xCoord.push_back(tmp1);
         inFile >> tmp2;
         yCoord.push_back(tmp2);
    }
```

Comment: can **while loop** be improved or converted to a **for loop** for this particular case as I already know the size of the vectors?

Comment: @TheCoder: Yes. Of course. You chack this answer now. I just change according to your code.

Comment: @TheCoder: If you like this answer you can accept this and upvote me.